# iOS WKWebView doesn't load http web content

Tags: ios, http, wkwebview

`WKWebView` doesn't load http requests, only https is working. My Url's strings are fetched from an API, so the url's links could be http and https. I did read about security, however the only thing I found was to add the following lines to the `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key> NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

However, in the `.plist` these keys don't exist. Is there any way to make `WKWebView` load http web content, and would the app be approved by the App Store?

I'm using Xcode 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Open your info.plist file from the project

2: add `App Transport Security Settings` in `Information Property List`

3: add `Allow Arbitrary Loads` in `App Transport Security Settings`

See the attached images

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How to load HTTP content in WKWebView and UIWebView: 

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-load-http-content-in-wkwebview-and-uiwebview

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore all transport security restrictions with the key your provided using the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I assume your example is not working due the space in the key:

```
<key> NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
```

Try to use the same value as you did but without the space.